# quotient of polynomial ring in two variables as a module isomorphic to polynomial ring in one variable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R=\Bbb C[t]$ be the ring of polynomials in $t$. I am studying the module $M:=R[x]/(x-t)$ as a $R$-module. Is it true that $M$ is isomorphic to $R$ as an $R$-module? It seems to be that the substitution map substituting $t=x$ would give such an isomorphism, but I am not sure if this map is injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evaluation map is not injective, but it **does** give you what you want.

> $$ev_t:\begin{cases}
> R[x]\to R \\
> p(x)\mapsto p(t)
> \end{cases}$$

is clearly **surjective**. So by the first isomorphism theorem, $R\cong R[x]/(x-t)=M$ since $(x-t)$ is the kernel of the homomorphism.

Comment: Ofcourse, thanks Adam.

Comment: How does one show that $(x - t)$ is the kernel of this map?

Comment: $(x-t)\subseteq \ker ev_t$ is obvious and the ideal is prime.

Answer (score 0):

For *any* ring $R$, and any $a\in R$, one has $R[x]/(x-a)\simeq R$. The map is induced by the map $R[x]\to R,\enspace p(x)\mapsto p(a)$, which is onto, and its kernel is the ideal $(x-a)$ of $R[x]$.

Comment: My inner nitpicker wants to emphasize that this only works for a *commutative* ring $R$. A reasonable assumption given that the OP is tagged [tag:commutative-algebra], but I want to protect the innocent passer-by :-)

Comment: Polynomial rings, in the usual sense, are defined over commutative rings.